# ora-38104columns referenced in on clause cannot be updated

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a trigger in which i am using a merge clause there is no error in the trigger but when an insert is done on that table after which the trigger is fired the insert statement is throwing ora-38104columns referenced in on clause cannot be updated on emp_id column

here is the merge statement

```
MERGE INTO stg_ta_payroll
    USING
    (select :NEW.ID_TM_ENR ID_TM_ENR, to_number(:NEW.ID_STR_RT) ID_STR_RT, :NEW.ID_EM ID_EM,
    nvl(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(:NEW.TS_EM_TM_IN,'YYMMDD')),0) V_TA_DATE,
    V_SESSION_NO V_SESSION_NO,
    :NEW.TS_EM_TM_IN TS_EM_TM_IN, :NEW.TS_EM_TM_OUT TS_EM_TM_OUT,
        DECODE(:NEW.TY_TM,'0',nvl(to_char(:NEW.TS_EM_TM_IN,'HH24MI'),'0000'),' ') V_TIME_IN,
        DECODE(:NEW.TY_TM,'0',nvl(to_char(:NEW.TS_EM_TM_OUT,'HH24MI'),'0000'),' ') V_TIME_OUT,
    V_MGR_OVRD V_MGR_OVRD,
    :NEW.ID_MGR ID_MGR,DECODE(:NEW.TY_TM,'XX','9',:NEW.TY_TM) TY_TM,
        decode(:NEW.TY_TM,'0',:NEW.OTHER_HRS_STR ,(NVL((:OLD.OTHER_HRS_STR),0)+NVL((:NEW.OTHER_HRS_STR),0)))OTHER_HRS_STR,
       -- V_OTHER_HRS_STR V_OTHER_HRS_STR,
    V_AREA V_AREA, V_ASSC_NAME V_ASSC_NAME, V_MISC_WAGES_DESC V_MISC_WAGES_DESC, V_SHRT_STR_NAME V_SHRT_STR_NAME,
    (:NEW.HRS_STR + :NEW.OTHER_HRS_STR) TOT_HRS from dual) STG
    ON (TIME_ENT_ID=STG.ID_TM_ENR AND to_number(STR_ID)=to_number(STG.ID_STR_RT) AND EMP_ID=STG.ID_EM)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET
      STATUS = null,
      EMP_ID = STG.ID_EM,
      TA_DATE = STG.V_TA_DATE,
      --SESSION_NO = STG.V_SESSION_NO,
      TIME_IN = STG.V_TIME_IN,
      TIME_OUT = STG.V_TIME_OUT,
      MGR_OVERRIDE = STG.V_MGR_OVRD,
      MGR_EMP_NO = STG.ID_MGR,
      MISC_WAGES_CODE = STG.TY_TM,
      MISC_WAGES_HRS = STG.OTHER_HRS_STR,
      AREA = STG.V_AREA,
      ASSOCIATE_NAME = STG.V_ASSC_NAME,
      MISC_WAGES_DESC = STG.V_MISC_WAGES_DESC,
      SHRT_STR_NAME = STG.V_SHRT_STR_NAME,
      HRS = STG.TOT_HRS,
      STG_OSB_PROCESS_DATE = null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ON` clause includes `AND EMP_ID=STG.ID_EM`, and when you get a match you're them setting `EMP_ID = STG.ID_EM`, which has no effect. You already know the two values are the same, so there is no point in setting the column to its current value. Usually it would just be pointless, but here it's causing the ORA-38104 error, as you can't set any `ON` clause column to anything, even itself.

Just remove that part of the `SET`, as it isn't doing anything except generating the error.

Comment: ya thank you @Alex Poole i googled it and found the answer i removed it from update clause and used it in ON clause now i am able to insert records also,but now the problem is coming in the decode statement where i am adding the old and new values based on this condition TIME_ENT_ID=STG.ID_TM_ENR AND to_number(STR_ID)=to_number(STG.ID_STR_RT) AND EMP_ID=STG.ID_EM,i am not able to get the added values if ty_tm is not equal to zero     can you please help i would really be thankful to you

Comment: @saniyamapari - asking a question here and then searching for the answer is the wrong way around surely; you should ask a question if you can't find the answer yourself? Although the error is fairly clear here anyway. I don't understand your new issue - you mention a decode but then show your `ON` condition. You have several decodes; not sure if you're getting the wrong value from one (which would be hard to diagnose without the schema and data), or an error. Either way, if you can't figure it out (after searching!) it should be a new question.

Comment: sorry but there was no reply for around 15min and it was urgent so i had to google and solve any ways thanx @Alex Poole